# React-Query not displaying Data even though GET is working

Tags: reactjs, react-query

I am currently trying to get data to display on my React App.

My query is set to:

```
interface ResultWrapper<T> {
result: T;
}
export interface FinancialData {
handleViewData: () => void;
symbol: string;
name: string;
stockExchange: string;
exchangeShortName: string;
currency: string;
}

export const useGetFinancialDataKey = 'get-financial-data';

const useGetFinancialData = (
  options: UseQueryOptions<FinancialData[], string> = {}
): UseQueryResult<FinancialData[], string> =>
   useQuery<FinancialData[], string>(
   useGetFinancialDataKey,
     async () =>
     (await axiosInstance.get<ResultWrapper<FinancialData[]>>. 
     ('https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/search? 
     query=AA&limit=10&exchange=NASDAQ&apikey=ENTERAPIKEY'
     )).data.result, options
     );


export default useGetFinancialData;
```

I have checked the network tab, and I am getting a response back:
[image: Network Tab]

However, whenever I go to the home page, nothing displays and whenever I call the query in my finance.tsx file, I get an undefined when using

```
const {data: financialData} = useGetFinancialData();
```

The full file in finance.tsx looks something like this:

```
    const Finance: React.FC = () => {
    const {data: financialData} = useGetFinancialData();
    const [searched, setSearched] = useState<string>('');
    const [dataToView, setDataToView] = useState<FinancialData>();
    const [isViewDialogOpen, setIsViewDialogOpen] = useState(false);
  
    const [page, setPage] = useState(0);
    const PER_PAGE = 10;
  
    const handleViewData = useCallback(
      (data: FinancialData) => {
        setDataToView(data)
        setIsViewDialogOpen(true);
      },
      [setDataToView, setIsViewDialogOpen]
    );
    const filteredRows = useMemo(()=>{
      const query = searched.toLowerCase();
      setPage(0);
    
      return financialData?.filter(
        (item) => 
        item.name.toLowerCase().includes(query)
      );
    }, [searched, financialData]);
  
    return (
        <Paper elevation={4}>
        <TableContainer>
        <Toolbar>
        <SearchBar
                placeholder="Search By Name"
                value={searched}
                onChange={(searchVal: string) => setSearched(searchVal)}
                onCancelSearch={() => setSearched('')}
              />
        </Toolbar>
        <Table>
          <TableHead>
            <TableRow>
              <TableCell>Symbol</TableCell>
              <TableCell>Name</TableCell>
              <TableCell>Currency</TableCell>
              <TableCell>Stock Exchange</TableCell>
              <TableCell>Exchange Short Name</TableCell>
            </TableRow>
          </TableHead>
          <TableBody>
            {filteredRows &&
            filteredRows.slice(page * PER_PAGE, page * PER_PAGE + PER_PAGE)
            .map((row,i) => (
              <FinancialDataRow
              key = {row.name}
              handleViewData={() => handleViewData(row)}
              symbol={row.symbol}
              name={row.name}
              currency={row.currency}
              stockExchange={row.stockExchange}
              exchangeShortName={row.exchangeShortName}
              />
            ))}
          </TableBody>
        </Table>
        </TableContainer>
      </Paper>
    );
  };
   
  export default Finance;
```

As you can see from below, nothing is returned because it is being returned as undefined, even though the data is being fetched:
[image]

Comment: Are you sure `.data.result` is correct? The preview doesn't show an object with a result field.

Comment: @windowsill you were right. needed to remove .result and my custom wrapper!

Answer (score 0):

thank you @windowsill for helping.

```
export interface FinancialData {
handleViewData: () => void;
symbol: string;
name: string;
stockExchange: string;
exchangeShortName: string;
currency: string;
}

export const useGetFinancialDataKey = 'get-financial-data';

const useGetFinancialData = (
options: UseQueryOptions<FinancialData[], string> = {}
 ): UseQueryResult<FinancialData[], string> => 
 useQuery<FinancialData[], string>(
  useGetFinancialDataKey,
 async () =>
(await axiosInstance.get<FinancialData[]>('https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/search?query=AA&limit=10&exchange=NASDAQ&apikey=blahblah'
))
.data,
options

);


 export default useGetFinancialData;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).